# EditText to double Android studio, this seems to work but doesn't look correct

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, double

I think I'm going a long way around when trying to set an EditText field to a double variable. Here is my method:

```
    public void setItemCost() {
        EditText x1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemCost);
        Editable x2 = x1.getText();
        String x3 = x2.toString();
        itemCost = Double.parseDouble(x3);
    }
```

As a relative noob to Java I'm just wondering if there is a better or more concise way of doing this. 
Also would I be better using floats for pricing?

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: Re `floats for pricing?`:  see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Sorry.

However, you can chain it like this

`itemCost = Double.parseDouble(x1.getText().toString());`